# how can i skip some GTEST ::testing::Combine case?

Tags: c++, googletest

```
INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(Foo, Foo1,
    Combine(Bool(),Bool(),Bool()));
```

I do **NOT** want to run the **Foo1** when these three values are **ALL TRUE**.
Which function I can use?

Comment: There is no such function provided by googletest. The easiest way would be to  early-exit out of the test case. If you really want to not instantiate the test for those cases, you would have to write a custom `Combine` that does the filtering. This cannot be done without using classes that are considered internal by googletest. Take a look at the implementation of [`CartesianProductGenerator`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/aee0f9d9b5b87796ee8a0ab26b7587ec30e8858e/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-param-util.h#L806) to see what this would look like.